# extracting information from a file using awk and storing it into a variable with bash

Tags: linux, file, unix, awk

i have a config file wiht the following content:

```
ip address file_location
ip address file_location
.
.
.
.
```

i would like my script test.sh to read from this file the ip address and the file location : here is my code:

```
while read line ; do
ip=`echo $line| awk '{print $1}'`
done <test.conf
```

Now, when i enter echo $ip (just to see if it works), it gives me blank.

Comment: Do you have an empty line at the end? Note that if you `echo $ip` after the block, it will print the last one you fetched.

Comment: it works, but it only prints the last line, while my file contains a lot of line and i would like the script to read them all.

Comment: But then what you is to store them into an array. Update explaining exactly what you want (or the next step on your program), so we can help better.

Comment: i see my mistake now. I think as you said i need to put it in an array. What i want, is to be able to extract all ip addresses and store then in the variable ip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be an approach to create a bash array:

```
$ declare -A mylist
$ i=1
$ while read line; do mylist[$i]=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}'); ((i++)); done < test.conf
```

Then you can access the values with:

```
$ for i in "${mylist[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
ip1
ip2
ip3
```

---

Or also, with [Jonathan Leffer's very interesting approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19320060/extracting-information-from-a-file-using-awk-and-storing-it-into-a-variable-with/19320680#comment28618575_19320680), you can populate the array with the following command:

```
mylist=( $(awk '{print $1}' test.conf) )
```

It will store data like this:

```
mylist=(ip1 ip2 ip3 ...)
```

Comment: Or even: `mylist=( $(awk '{print $1}' test.conf) )` since by definition the `$1` from `awk` will not contain any spaces.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - you really should post that as an answer as it is the correct one.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I really like your approach. If you don't mind, I add it into my answer. If you want to add a new answer for it, don't hesitate to do so and delete its part in my answer. It's been very interesting to learn this way of populating an array!

Answer (score 1):

To read a file into variables, you should not even need to step out of bash into awk

```
while read -r v_ip _ v_test_location; do
  printf "%s %s\n" "$v_ip" "$v_test_location";
done < test.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment is executed in the inner shell of the `while` loop, so it has no effect on the `ip` variable outside it. Consider doing this instead:

```
ip=$(awk '/IMPORTANT_LINE_REGEXP/ {print $1}' test.conf)
```

Comment: Oops, rushed. Thank you.

Comment: It will happen the same the user is commenting: it just stores the last value. I think the answer will involve creating a bash array.